# CakePHP get form query, Error: An Internal Error Has Occurred

Tags: forms, cakephp, get

I use `get` form for searching keywords. (CakePHP 2.2.5)

I see weird problems.
Firstly from [CakePHP documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#accessing-querystring-parameters) : `$foo = $this->request->query('value_that_does_not_exist');` give

> Error: An Internal Error Has Occurred.
>
> > Method query does not exist

I tried that in both Controller and the view.
According to the manual it can be used to:

> ...read the url query array in an error free manner.

Btw,

```
$foo = $this->request->query['value_that_exist'];
```

works fine but I have to check it with “isset()“

Is it a CakePHP bug? I tested with fresh `2.2.5` install.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not a bug. The `query()` method was introduced in CakePHP 2.3.0-beta (see http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/lorenzo/2012/10/28/cakephp_2_3_0-beta_released#cakerequest) and hence it is not available in CakePHP 2.2.5.